# Transparent activity content does not match parent

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am displaying transparent activity  but its content does not match parent  here is my style code.`

> ```
>     <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
>
>     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
>
>     <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
>
>     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
>
>     <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
>
>     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
> </style>
> ```

`

Then i change  `android:windowIsFloating` attribute value from true to false its start match the parent but transparency turn in to black.Please suggest me what is the issue,i would be thankful to you.

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
```

To

```
 <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
```

**Solved**

**I solve this by changing windowIsTranslucent attribute from false to true **

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>

  to  

<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better you use Alpha for the particular view(such as Root view) for Ex:

```
android:alpha="0.95"
```

Comment: Thank i solve this **I solve this by changing windowIsTranslucent attribute from false to true ** 

    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>

      to  

    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>